# Pandas: How do I loop through and remove rows where a column has a single entry

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe with some number of columns (Below is the code for a simple dataframe but the real dataframe has over 100 columns):

```
X = pd.DataFrame([["A","Z"],["A","Z"],["B","Z"]],columns=["COL1","COL2"])
```

What I want to do is to go through every column and remove rows where only a single instance of something happens. E.g., in column 1 we only have one instance of 'B' so I'd like to delete the row on that basis.

However, I would like to go through every single column of the dataframe and keep removing rows where I have such instances.

The following code works for when I specify the name:

```
X = X[X.groupby('COL1').COL1.transform(len) > 1]
```

However, I'm not sure how to loop through with this code. Obviously I can manually enter every column name but I wanted to do this more properly. Obviously the following doesn't work:

```
for column in X:
    X[X.groupby(column).column.transform(len)>1]

    COL1    COL2
0   A   Z
1   A   Z
2   B   Y
```

Sorry if this has been asked. I found a lot of similar questions but haven't found one where we aren't manually specifying the column.

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if you need additional information

Comment: Your for loop should give you an error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'column'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use duplicated as so:

```
X = pd.DataFrame([["A","Z"],["A","Z"],["B","Z"], ["A","Y"]],columns=["COL1","COL2"])

for column in X:
    X = X[X[column].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
  COL1 COL2
0    A    Z
1    A    Z
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is there a similarly easy way to solve the issue if we were to want to tackle the case where we have 2 or 3 entries? E.g., remove all rows if a string appears less than 3 times in a column?

Comment: @Nicklovn I would recommend you open a new question for that.And please accept this if it solved your question!

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is to fix your code

```
X[X.groupby('COL1').COL2.transform('count')>1]
  COL1 COL2
0    A    Z
1    A    Z
```

Usually I will do `duplicated`

```
X[X.COL1.duplicated(keep=False)]
  COL1 COL2
0    A    Z
1    A    Z
```

Comment: Appreciate the correction to my code and the smarter alternative!