# Pandas: Loop through DataFrame columns and remove rows with variables that have less than i observations

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frame.

```
X = pd.DataFrame([["A","Z"],["A","Z"],["A","Z"],["B","Y"],["B","Y"]],columns=["COL1","COL2"])
```

Suppose I have the above dataframe. COL1 contains 3 A's and 2 B's. COL2 contains 3 Z's and 2 Y's.

What I'm trying to do is search each column and find the rows where there is less than i of a variable (E.g. in this case I search each column and find what rows have fewer than 3 entries).

In this case I have a bunch of duplicate entries but it's just presented like that for simplicity.

Link to my previous question:

[Pandas: How do I loop through and remove rows where a column has a single entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129701/pandas-how-do-i-loop-through-and-remove-rows-where-a-column-has-a-single-entry/57129727?noredirect=1#comment100785374_57129727)

Please let me know if clarification is needed.

Comment: Do columns always have same number of variables, at the same position? What if `COL2` has `[Z Z Y Y Y]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subset and keep False params

```
X = X[X.duplicated(subset=list(X.columns), keep=False)]
```

output:

```
  COL1 COL2
0    A    Z
1    A    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
i=3
X[X.groupby(X.columns.tolist()).COL1.transform('count')>=i]
  COL1 COL2
0    A    Z
1    A    Z
2    A    Z
```